# 2 ganttbar for one wp

Tags: gantt, bar

I'm looking for something to make a double `ganttbar` for every WP, so I can put the estimated time, and the real time spent on each task.

Something like in the picture [image]

As you may understand, the blue is for the estimated time, and orange for the actual time spent, so I will show any kind of delay.

I've already tried making a second bar, but it draw it a bit to far below, as you can see I tried using the `top bar shit` to put it a bit higher but, I can't really manage the shift of the label. 
[image]

I know there should be something like `yshift=<factor>` but I'm unable to make it work.

Sorry guys, I completely forgot to share my code...

``

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside, openany]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage[a4paper, total={17cm, 25cm}]{geometry}
    \usepackage[document]{ragged2e} %
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{pgfgantt} %per il gannt
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{./images/}}

    %%%%%%
   %% Some more packages
    %%%%%%
    %       Gantt, per avere solo il numero delle settimane
    \newcounter{myWeekNum}
    \stepcounter{myWeekNum}
    %
   \newcommand{\myWeek}{\themyWeekNum
       \stepcounter{myWeekNum}
       \ifnum\themyWeekNum=53
       \setcounter{myWeekNum}{1}
       \else\fi
   }


 \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %% impostazioni 
    \setcounter{myWeekNum}{39}
    \ganttset{%
        calendar week text={\myWeek{}}%
    }
    \begin{ganttchart}[
    y unit chart=7mm,
    x unit = 1.1mm,
    %           hgrid,
    vgrid={*{6}{draw=none}, dotted},    % barre ogni 6 giorni
    expand chart=\textwidth,
    time slot format=isodate,
    time slot unit=month,
    link mid=.45,
    link bulge=2.3,
    link tolerance=2,
    ]{2019-09-16}{2020-01-14}
    %           \gantttitle{Progetto Corso}{18} \\
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname, week=39} \\
    \ganttnewline [thick, black]
    %%Pianificazione
    \ganttgroup{Pianificazione}{2019-09-16}{2019-09-19} \\
    \ganttbar[name= Pian, bar height=.4,bar label node/.append yshift=-0.2,]{Pianificazione}{2019-09-16}{2019-09-19} \\
    \ganttbar[name= Pian2, bar height=.4, bar top shift = -.3, bar/.append style={fill=red!50}, ]{}{2019-09-16}{2019-09-19} \\
    %% Sviluppo
    \ganttgroup{Sviluppo}{2019-09-20}{2019-11-3} \\
    \ganttbar[name= svC]{Case}{2019-09-20}{2019-09-29} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Motore}{2019-09-30}{2019-10-20} \\
    %           \ganttnewline
    %           \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7}
    %           \ganttnewline
    \ganttbar{Riduttore}{2019-10-7}{2019-11-3}\\
    \ganttbar{Ricezione comando}{2019-10-14}{2019-11-3} 
    \ganttnewline [thick, black]
    \end{ganttchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Gannt progetto corso}
    \label{fig:Gannt_1}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

``

And if this also work for the `ganttgroup`, it really would be amazing.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please share the code you have so far.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot th code...